# Ionic - How to create a border around my button when being click?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Currently I am trying to make my mobile app to be like, a default border around my button "OFF" when i go in my app. After "ON" button is being click, the border will be around my "ON" button, When i click "OFF" button, the border will change back to be around my "OFF" button.

HTML:

```
<ion-view title="Single Projector Room" id="page9">

 <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
     <button class="button back-button buttons button-clear header-item" ng-click="goBack()">
       <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-back"> Back</i> 
     </button>
   </ion-nav-buttons>

   <ion-content padding="true" style="background: url(img/EDD79InSMCeYeMOSchjm_remote.jpg) no-repeat center;background-size:cover;" class="has-header">

   <div class="row">
     <div class="col"><br><br><br><br></div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
   <div class="col col-offset-5 col-30 text-center"><h4 style="color: #FFFFFF;">Single Projector Control</h4></div>
   <div class="col col-30 text-center"><h4 style="color: #FFFFFF;">Screen Control</h4></div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
     <div class="col col-offset-5 col-30 text-center"><button class="button button-balanced button-large icon-right ion-power">On</button></div>
     <div class="col col-30 text-center"><button class="button button-dark button-large icon-right ion-arrow-up-c">Up</button></div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
     <div class="col col-offset-5 col-30 text-center"><button class="button button-assertive button-large icon-right ion-android-cancel">Off</button></div>
     <div class="col col-30 text-center"><button class="button button-dark button-large icon-right ion-arrow-down-c">Down</button></div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
     <div class="col"><br><br></div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
   <div class="col col-offset-5 col-30 text-center"><h4 style="color: #FFFFFF;">Mic Control</h4></div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
     <div class="col col-offset-5 col-30 text-center"><button class="button button-balanced button-large icon-right ion-power">On</button></div>
   </div>

   <div class="row">
     <div class="col col-offset-5 col-30 text-center"><button class="button button-assertive button-large icon-right ion-android-cancel">Off</button></div>
   </div>
 </div>

   </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

controller.js:

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])

.controller("remoteCtrl", function($scope, $stateParams, $state, $ionicHistory) {

$scope.single = function() {
    $state.go("singleProjectorRoom");
  }
$scope.dual = function() {
    $state.go("dualProjectorRoom");
  }

$scope.myGoBack = function() {
                $ionicHistory.goBack();
            }

})

.controller('menuCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', // The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams) {


}])

.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $ionicHistory, sharedUtils, $state, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
    $rootScope.extras = false;  // For hiding the side bar and nav icon

    // When the user logs out and reaches login page,
    // we clear all the history and cache to prevent back link
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(ev) {
      if(ev.targetScope !== $scope){
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
        $ionicHistory.clearCache();
      }
    });


    //Check if user already logged in
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {

    //Removes back link to login page
        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
          historyRoot: true
        });
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(true);  // Sets up the sideMenu dragable
        $rootScope.extras = true;
        sharedUtils.hideLoading();
        $state.go('tabs.home', {}, {location: "replace"});

      }
    });


    $scope.loginEmail = function(formName,cred) {


      if(formName.$valid) {  // Check if the form data is valid or not

          sharedUtils.showLoading(); //starts the loading popup

          //Email Login via Firebase
          firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(cred.email,cred.password).then(function(result) {

                // You dont need to save the users session in your local session or cookies. Firebase handles it.

        // You only need to :
                // 1. clear the login page history from the history stack so that you cant come back
                // 2. Set rootScope.extra;
                // 3. Turn off the loading
                // 4. Got to menu page


              $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                historyRoot: true   //1
              });
              $rootScope.extras = true;  //2
              sharedUtils.hideLoading();  //3
              $state.go('tabs.home', {}, {location: "replace"}); //4

            },
            function(error) {
              sharedUtils.hideLoading();
              sharedUtils.showAlert("ERROR!","Authentication Error");
            }
        );

      }else{
        sharedUtils.showAlert("ERROR!","Enter in email format");
      }



    };
})

.controller("logoutCtrl", function($scope, $state, $ionicPopup, $rootScope, sharedUtils, $ionicHistory,$ionicSideMenuDelegate, intentService, errorMessageService) {

    $scope.logoutNo = function() {
      intentService.setloginFlagTrue();
      $state.go("tabs.home");
      console.log("Logout is reverted.The flag is now set as " + intentService.getloginFlagStatus());
    }

    $scope.logoutYes = function() {

      sharedUtils.showLoading();

      // Main Firebase logout
      firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {

        errorMessageService.write("Thank you","You have logout successfully.");

        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);  // To remove the sidemenu white space

        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
          historyRoot: true
        });


        $rootScope.extras = false;
        sharedUtils.hideLoading();
        $state.go('login', {}, {location: "replace"});

      }, function(error) {
         sharedUtils.showAlert("Error","Logout Failed")
      });

    }
})

.controller('singleProjectorRoomCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', // The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams) {
$scope.goBack = function() {
window.history.back();
}
}])

.controller('dualProjectorRoomCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', // The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams) {
$scope.goBack = function() {
window.history.back();
}

}])

.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', // The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $stateParams) {


}])
```

Comment: have you tried `ng-class` or `ng-style`?  those are the typical directives in angular for adding css to HTML dynamically....

Comment: @Claies I manage to use ng-class to change the colour of my ON/OFF button.